# How can I access a child array in a Laravel Collection?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a database search that returns thousands of entries which I then group by two columns like so:

```
$results = $merged->groupBy(['source', 'parent']);
```

The result is Laravel Collection with the following structure, grouped first by the 'source' (`1_k12_fill_trypsin_dig`), then the 'parent' (`2, 4, 9, 10...`), and each 'parent' has some number of children:

[image: [ 'GROUP 1' => []]

I want to sort the parents by the number of children they have. So, in this example, I would want '4' to be at the top, so that the child count serves as the 'truth test' in some closure. I just don't know how to access these elements. I was hoping to use Collection methods as opposed to looping through with vanilla PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sorting by their count?

Sort by source count

```
$merged
    ->groupBy(...)
    ->sort(function ($sources) {
        return collect($sources)->count();
    });
```

Sort by parent count

```
$merged
    ->groupBy(...)
    ->sort(function ($sources) {
        return collect($sources)
            ->sum(function ($parents) {
                return count($parents);
            });
    });
```

---

To sort only the nested array, you could use  `map()` or `transform()`.

```php
$merged
    ->groupBy(['source', 'parent'])
    ->map(function ($source) {
        return collect($source)
            ->sortByDesc(function ($parent) {
                return count($parent);
            })
            ->all();
    });

// PHP 7.4+
$merged
    ->groupBy(['source', 'parent'])
    ->map(fn($source) => 
        collect($source)
            ->sortByDesc(fn($parent) => count($parent))
            ->all()
    );
```

I used Faker to generate collections similar to yours and it worked for me.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this would turn each 'source' entry into a collection, determine its number of children, and return that to the sort closure? I think I need to go one level deeper, to sort by parents. Because `$item` in this case is the `1_k12_full_trypsin_digest`'s corresponding array, yes?

Comment: It's possible to sort by parent quantities, just need to alter the closure a bit. Somehing like that.

Comment: passing a closure to sort() and returning a number just tells the collection how to sort. For example if the first item returns 4 and the second item returns 1, then the second item gets placed before the first item once the collection is sorted.

Comment: I tried your second code block and it doesn't do quite what I'm looking for. I think your code sorts the sources by the number of parents? I just want to sort the parents themselves by their number of children. The order of the sources actually does not matter to me, but your examples are helping me understand how this works nonetheless

Comment: So you want to sort the nested arrays?

Comment: I feel like calling 'sort' after 'groupBy' will sort the sources. I only want to sort the parents by their number of children, but I'm not sure how to access these. Maybe by calling each() first, then sort()?

Comment: Yes, I believe so!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232537/discussion-between-vranvs-and-igp).

Comment: I've edited another possibility in the answer.